# Creation of IBOutlet causing SIGABRT error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, error-handling, iboutlet

I'm working on a project with a user profile static table view controller where a user could view and change their personal settings through text fields and toggles in the table. Before I connect the text fields and toggles to the corresponding class file, the profile view opens fine, but immediately after I add a connection, upon hitting the profile button that would normally initiate the segue to the profile view, the app crashes and produces a Thread 1: SIGABRT error. I am sure that there are no duplicate or unlinked connections that would normally cause this error and am very confused as to why this is happening.

Comment: Add the Exception breakpoint and get the exception reason.

Comment: @vadian I'm a very new developer would you mind explaining where in my code this breakpoint should be added?

Comment: I've added the exception breakpoint but still the error produces no message in the debugger, I tried adding the po $arg1 action to the breakpoint as some of recommended but that yielded no further results either

Comment: After the crash press the Continue button in the debug area

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you deleted any outlets from your .swift files, that are still present in your storyboard.

Comment: Did that, unless I'm going crazy it seems like all the outlets matchup. If I delete every outlet then it runs fine, but the moment I add a single connection to the swift file it throws this error